# C# tasks(with or without TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously) performance vs thread loop , .net threading is worse?

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, task-parallel-library, parallel-processing

i was thinking about the best technique of work when processing queue of actions (the order of operation was important so every operation must come after it's previous one)

i'm pretty disappointed from the performance results of running a Task with continuation options that suppose to run on the same thread (i was expecting to have similar results as thread running in a loop).... i would appreciate any comments about these performance results, btw - it appears that maybe JIT have improved performance so that running without any threading in some cases is better than with threading, in my example below u can see that the working on array size of 450K items was faster in main thread than other thread running a loop

---

### **The methods that were considered:**

- **running in simple for loop** on each action (sequential approach)
- **running a Task.ContinueWith method**. this method is being executed on a thread pool thread and each other action is being also performed after it's previous (thread pool decide on which thread it runs on).
- **running a Task.ContinueWith method with TaskContinuationOptions** set to TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, this is causing all the tasks to be performed on the same thread
- **runing on a seperated thread** - new System.Threading.Thread working with for loop on the action

---

### **Method Code:**

I've created simple tester application that runs on and array and sets arr[i] = i * i
where i is: 100,000 to 450,000 (jumps of 50,000 between each test)

### **Results:**

> ------------------------- Running test with 100000 items & iterations---------------------------
>
> Simple for results :**24.0013 MS**
>
> Task.ContinueWith() result :**691.0395 MS**
>
> Task.ContinueWith(TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously) result :**91.0052 MS**
>
> Thread.Start result : **16.0009 MS**
>
> *{skip...skip...skip - this is too long...}*
>
> ------------------------- Running test with 450000 items & iterations---------------------------
>
> Simple for results :**16.0009 MS**
>
> Task.ContinueWith() result : **3686.2108 MS**
>
> Task.ContinueWith(TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously) result:**415.0238 MS**
>
> Thread.Start result : **35.002 MS**
>
> Press any key to exit

### **Source Code**

```
static int max = 100000;
    static int[] array;
    static DateTime start;
    static int valueOfMax = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (valueOfMax = max; valueOfMax < max * 5; valueOfMax += (max/2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("------------------------- Running test with {0} items & iterations---------------------------", valueOfMax));
            array = new int[valueOfMax];
            start = DateTime.Now;
            Console.Write("Simple for results :                                                                 ");
            for (int i = 0; i < valueOfMax; i++)
            {
                doSomething(i);
            }

            start = DateTime.Now;
            Action<int> action = doSomething;
            Task lastTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { int p = 4; });
            Console.Write("Task.ContinueWith() result :                                                         ");
            for (int i = 0; i < valueOfMax; i++)
            {
                var valueOfI = i;
                lastTask = lastTask.ContinueWith((task) => doSomething(valueOfI));
            }
            lastTask.Wait();

            start = DateTime.Now;
            lastTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { int p = 4; });
            Console.Write("Task.ContinueWith(TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously) result :             ");
            for (int i = 0; i < valueOfMax; i++)
            {
                var valueOfI = i;
                lastTask = lastTask.ContinueWith((task) => doSomething(valueOfI), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
            }
            lastTask.Wait();

            start = DateTime.Now;
            Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < valueOfMax; i++)
                {
                    doSomething(i);
                }
            });
            Console.Write("Thread.Start result :                                                                ");
            t.Start();
            t.Join();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void doSomething(int i)
    {
        array[i] = i * i;

        if ((i+1) == valueOfMax)
        {
            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            var diff = end - start;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} MS", diff.TotalMilliseconds));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a discussion site, it's a Q&A site. Do you have an actual question, or are you just looking for a discussion?

Comment: my question is how should i manage my queue of actions, having the following information I've just supplied. it appears that there's a performance issue when needing to perform task continuation. i'm looking for an example where i'll get better performance of Task.ContinueWith() rather than thread running on a queue

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't use `DateTime.Now` for performance measurements, it's too imprecise for that. You should use `StopWatch` instead. In this case, doing that makes the measurements a lot different.

Second, when you call a method for the first time, it has to be JIT compiled, so you should probably ignore the results from the first round.

Third, you should run it in Release more without debugger attached (Ctrl+F5, not F5), if you didn't already do that.

Fourth, don't forget about the GC, it can change your measurements in unpredictable ways.

Now, let's think about what you're going to do: If you want to run some code in a loop, then simply run it in a loop. Simple loops are extremely efficient, it will be very hard to come with anything with performance close to that.

What about `Task`s? I think it's not realistic to use them for operations as simple as this. If you want to run simple operation fast repeatedly, you should make your code as simple as possible, not involve closures, heap allocations, thread synchronization and who knows what else, which are all necessary if you use `Task`s the way you do.

To conclude, if you have simple operation that you want to execute a lot of times, just use simple loop. I don't see any reason to use anything else. With a loop, you know the computer will be executing your code and (almost) nothing else.

`Task`s and `ContinueWith()` do have their place, especially if you have some more complicated control flows (like having some task that does something, then two different tasks that start after that one completes and then another task that starts after both of them complete). Or if you want to make your application composable. But if try to use them instead of a `for` loop, don't be surprised that the results are less than stellar.

Comment: thanks for the detailed replay! i'm planning to run the code tomorrow with your suggestions (no debugging, release and stopwatch) and i promise to update about the results. my eventual code does suppose to have very high complexity since it's suppose to work with sockets. i'm planning to use it as follows: Socket->data deserialied async to object-> objects are sent to a queue (ordered as received). i wanted to be sure that i'm writing my code as best as i can (socket will be recieving plenty of packets)

Comment: the results:(100K items:-->)Simple for results :1.82 MS Task.ContinueWith() result : 595.4028 MS Task.ContinueWith(TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously) result :80.8529 MS
Thread.Start Result :1.4597 MS
----------Running test with 450000 items & iterations--------
Simple for results : 2.5729 MS
Task.ContinueWith() result :2389.4624 MS
Task.ContinueWith(TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously) result :323.9456 MS
Thread.Start result :3.4324 MS

Answer (score 0):

You say that all items need to be executed sequentially. This means that at most one CPU can be busy. So you are doing the same amount of work, still on a single CPU but with additional overhead. *Of course*, this is slower. I am not sure what you were expecting.

I think what you really want is to have a dedicated thread processing your work items and pulling those from a BlockingCollection. Here is a very nice tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx

Comment: basically i have a component that suppose to have items queued for execution.i'm creating this component to have some kind of thread-safe code that can be executed of other actual thread rather than the main thread.so basically what i need to do is to decide how i want to implement it, i can make a concurrent thread that works on a queue and dispatched whenever new item arrive but i thought Microsoft has planned to make life easier to programmers by supplying their version to it by using Task.ContinueWith

Comment: another reason to use Task is to have MS descide how to manage the amount of threads (i plan to have several instances of this component and i didn't wanted to write this code in a way that will cause the number of components (=thread) bigger than the actual available cpu's on that machine (this could cause major performance issues...)

Comment: Please see my edit about BlockingCollection. This is probably what you need.